# PhonePe QR ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, payment-gateway, payment

I have a QR image and document of PhonePe QR code. I'm seeking for help to know about the following:

is it possible to detect when QR is being scanned by any device and send data like amount, etc ?

How I'll get the information about payment status on my web application?

Answer (score 3):

You can check the status of payment using check API.

If Payment Done - Then check API return Successful 
If Payment Pending- Then check API return Payment Not Done
If Payment Decline by user  - Then check API return Payment decline by user.

https://developer.phonepe.com/reference#check-transaction-status-1